# MVC in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have seen in sites which were built using CodeIngniter framework there there is **'index.php'** in the URI. Is that necessary?.

For example:
example.com/index.php/products/view/shoes

Is it possible to make it:

example.com/products/view/shoes

Answer (score 2):

of course, you have to rewrite the routes with an .htaccess, [here it is](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

Comment: +1 for linking to official documentation with a CI-specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sites like this are making use of "mod_rewrite", a module for Apache. So long as mod_rewrite is installed on your web server, you can set htaccess rules that route a web request like /products/view/shoes through index.php (or whatever page you want). URL rewriting is a large topic with many facets and you'll be able to learn more through some Google searches.

[Apache's URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

[IIS Equivalent of mod_rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and [here is where the directions are](http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/remove-codeigniter-index-php.html)